# 502 bad gateway on Ngnix+Gunicorn+Django configuratoin

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-deployment

I am deploying a django webapp on digitalocean and I am using Nginx and Gunicorn.

And when I open my url, it shows 502 bad gateway.

In the nginx_errors.log, I find the following error message:

```
[error] 12229#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/demo/webapps/hello/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.45.6.78, server: demohello.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/demo/webapps/hello/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "demohello.com"
```

Is it because my nginx configuration is wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the configurations for gunicorn correctly which is in **/etc/init/gunicorn.conf**.

Be careful with:

- --name=**django_project** \
- --pythonpath=**django_project** \
- **django_project**.*wsgi:application*